# Console.log not working while in function

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

```
function getComputerChoice() {


 const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
 console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));

}
```

not printing to console sorry if it's obvious new to javascript

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Where and how do you call `getComputerChoice`? You _do_ call the function, right?

Comment: Of course it's not printing anything when your not calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did declare a function but you didnt call it

```js
function getComputerChoice() {

 const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
 console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));

}

 getComputerChoice()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to log the random array, so to pick from an array its usually array[num/string].

Hope this helps!

```js
function getComputerChoice() {

 const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
 console.log(choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);

}

 getComputerChoice()
```

Comment: If it's not logging anything, that's not the problem - it would at least have logged the index

Comment: I think what he/she means is that its logging something that isn't in the index.  As you can see he/she is new to javascript, common mistakes.